# Checkbox value doesn,t inserted in mysql

Tags: java, android

i am trying to insert checkbox value into my mysql database, there is no error in the program...
But i cannot get the value into the database.
In the database it show empty...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CheckBox box;
Button btn_test;
private static final String REGISTER_URL="http://192.168.0.106/test/checkin.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);


    box = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    btn_test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn_test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerUser();
        }
    });
}

private void registerUser() {
    box.isChecked();
    String date = box1.toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    register(date);
}

private void register(String date){
    String urlSuffix = "?date=" + date;
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
```

how can i get the value from the check box and inserted in the database

Comment: post register method code.

Comment: Check your API first in postman or any other tool

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,May be it will help you :)

> box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>
> > ```
> >    @Override
> >    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {               
> >    if(isChecked){
> >    String date = box1.toString().trim().toLowerCase();
> >    register(date); } } }  );
> > ```

Comment: "satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() "   What is that satView